# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, fragment

I am getting these type of  exception while creating project in android i have one mainactivity and some fragments but when i am running app then i am getting error like these i am pasting error here ,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.MeraIndore/.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d008e
```

Code for mainactivity.java is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, FragmentOne.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
FragmentTwo.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    private SliderLayout mDemoSlider;

    DrawerLayout drawer;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
////apply from: './gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
///fragment mnanager

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            Class fragmentClass = null;
            fragment = new Fragmentforslider();
          fragmentClass= FragmentOne.class;
            try {

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
        }



        //   getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
/*
        mDemoSlider = (SliderLayout)findViewById(R.id.slider);

        HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
        url_maps.put("Hannibal", "http://static2.hypable.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/hannibal-season-2-release-date.jpg");
        url_maps.put("Big Bang Theory", "http://tvfiles.alphacoders.com/100/hdclearart-10.png");
        url_maps.put("House of Cards", "http://cdn3.nflximg.net/images/3093/2043093.jpg");
        url_maps.put("Game of Thrones", "http://images.boomsbeat.com/data/images/full/19640/game-of-thrones-season-4-jpg.jpg");

        HashMap<String,Integer> file_maps = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        file_maps.put("Hannibal",R.drawable.hannibal);
        file_maps.put("Big Bang Theory",R.drawable.bigbang);
        file_maps.put("House of Cards", R.drawable.house);
        file_maps.put("Game of Thrones", R.drawable.game_of_thrones);

        for(String name : file_maps.keySet()){
            TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
            // initialize a SliderLayout
            textSliderView
                    .description(name)
                    .image(file_maps.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                    .setOnSliderClickListener(this);


            //add your extra information
            textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
            textSliderView.getBundle()
                    .putString("extra",name);

            mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
        }
        mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.ZoomIn);
        mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
        //mDemoSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
        mDemoSlider.setCustomIndicator((PagerIndicator) findViewById(R.id.custom_indicator));
        mDemoSlider.setDuration(4000);
        mDemoSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    /*    ListView l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.transformers);
        l.setAdapter(new TransformerAdapter(this));
        l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(((TextView) view).getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((TextView) view).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

//*/

       NavigationView rightNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_right_view);
        rightNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        rightNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle Right navigation view item clicks here.
                int id = item.getItemId();
                Fragment fragment = null;
                Class fragmentClass = null;

                if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
                    fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right Drawer - Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
                    fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right Drawer - Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {
                    fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right Drawer - Help", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
                    fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right Drawer - About", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
              else if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
                    fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left Drawer - Import", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
                    fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left Drawer - Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
                    fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left Drawer - Slideshow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
                    fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left Drawer - Tools", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
                    fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left Drawer - Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
                    fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left Drawer - Send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                try {
                    fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

                // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
                item.setChecked(true);
                // Set action bar title
                setTitle(item.getTitle());
                // Close the navigation drawer
                DrawerLayout mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                mDrawer.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
/*
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {


        mDemoSlider.stopAutoCycle();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
        Toast.makeText(this,slider.getBundle().get("extra") + "",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        } else if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {  //Closes the Appropriate Drawer
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
*/
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            case R.id.action_openRight:
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);

            break;

            case R.id.action_custom_indicator:
                mDemoSlider.setCustomIndicator((PagerIndicator) findViewById(R.id.custom_indicator));
                break;
            case R.id.action_custom_child_animation:
                mDemoSlider.setCustomAnimation(new ChildAnimationExample());
                break;
            case R.id.action_restore_default:
                mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
                mDemoSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
                break;
            case R.id.action_github:
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                break;
        }




        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
/*
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Log.d("Slider Demo", "Page Changed: " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    */
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle Right navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = null;

        if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            fragmentClass = FragmentOne.class;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right Drawer - Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
            fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right Drawer - Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {
            fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right Drawer - Help", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
            fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right Drawer - About", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left Drawer - Import", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left Drawer - Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left Drawer - Slideshow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left Drawer - Tools", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left Drawer - Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
            fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left Drawer - Send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Show `MainActivity ` class code

Comment: i think you are missing default view, and as per `Prosper K` said, show code.

Comment: The Error says that you are missing a layout. double check xml layout and main activity code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by other user you must focus on missing id view , and you must try to figure out that one missing id . And second thing is you are using fragment in mainactivity then just try to see xml of fragments also , i think missing id is refers to one of element of fragment view .

Answer (score 1):

In your exception just try to focus on these line ,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d008e
```

Here in your main activity code you had applied operation on id 0x7f0d008e but it is not in your xml file.